# Blank nft mint transaction

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, nft, hardhat, openzeppelin

I have issue i succesfully minted and send nft but when I checking this nft on etherscan i see nft transaction but don't see img same on metamask i don't see any kind of nft or any nft photos
Attachments:

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Code 1

```
import "./nftestate.sol";

contract BidContract is REALESTATE {
    struct Bid {
        address bidder;
        uint amount;
    }
    address public ownerr;
    uint public highestBid;
    address public highestBidder;
    event newbid(uint256 indexed highestBid, address indexed highestBidder);

    mapping(address => Bid) public bids;

    constructor() {
        ownerr = msg.sender;
    }

    function hisghestbidcheck() public view returns (uint256) {
        return highestBid;
    }

    function bid() public payable {
        require(msg.value > highestBid, "Bid too low");

        if (highestBidder != address(0)) {
            payable(highestBidder).transfer(highestBid);
        }

        highestBid = msg.value;
        highestBidder = msg.sender;
        bids[msg.sender] = Bid(msg.sender, msg.value);
        emit newbid(highestBid, highestBidder);
    }

    function endAuction() public {
        require(msg.sender == ownerr, "Only owner can end auction");
        require(highestBidder != address(0), "No bids received");

        payable(ownerr).transfer(highestBid);
        highestBid = 0;
        safeMint(highestBidder);
        highestBidder = address(0);
    }
}
```

Code 2

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract REALESTATE is ERC721, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;

    constructor() ERC721("RealEsate", "RE") {}

    function _baseURI() internal pure override returns (string memory) {
        return "bafybeia435jagllnx7hgzidfd4q7jztp2u2a7di2h5xl6an6gbk5x6phzi";
    }

    function safeMint(address to) public onlyOwner {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the information you've given it looks like you are missing two bits.

The first being in the `_baseURI` function you are returning a hardcoded IPFS address. This is missing the `ipfs://` prefix to indicate that this is a ipfs address. It also will require a `/` at the end so the token ID suffix is not appending directly to the IPFS hash.

Secondly, metamask and other platforms use the `tokenURI()` function to retrieve the NFT metadata, the result will be `<BASE_URI><TOKEN_ID>` which in this case will be `bafybeia435jagllnx7hgzidfd4q7jztp2u2a7di2h5xl6an6gbk5x6phzi0` the zero at the end is the token ID of that minted NFT. You can see the [implementation here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/ab2604ac5b791adf3c5e2397e65128cb56954edd/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L93)

Looking at the base IPFS URI, it points to an index which contains one file called `photo-1600585154340-be6161a56a0c.jpg`, you can see this [here](https://ipfsexplorer.online/ipfs/bafybeia435jagllnx7hgzidfd4q7jztp2u2a7di2h5xl6an6gbk5x6phzi). I am assuming that this is the photo that you would want displayed.

For this to work you would need a file at that IPFS address called `0` which follows the [ERC721 metadata standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721#specification:%7E:text=ERC721%20Metadata%20JSON%20Schema) for ERC-721 which has an image property which points to the image you want to display.

I would recommend to use [pinata](https://www.pinata.cloud/) to handle the uploads to IPFS and metadata creation as this can get tricky :)

Comment: i make few changes but this still dont work  first change New ipfs address now look like this  ```function _baseURI() internal pure override returns (string memory) {
        return
            "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmToLt8pdvBAMvX3iTvcig6Tw4Sh3sP5uGdK19o7asV74B";
    } ```and in safeMint function i set   `tokenId = 0;`  and  i started using piniata and changed photo name to 0 and still don't work

Comment: Attachemts: https://imgur.com/a/JuqqvGP